# How to check (.) fullstop in var javascript using onchange?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check (`.`) fullstop in var javascript using onchange ?

```
EG: var xxx = 120.00;
```

What function that can check (`.`) fullstop in this var

I use to use `isnan` but not work ,

If i use on Event `onkeypress` , I can use `keyCode` for check.

But i want to use even `onchange`, Can i do that ?

Comment: What exactly will be changing?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need this?

Comment: onchange of something use it`xxx.indexOf('.')` is this?

Comment: I don't get it ... `onchange` of what? Do you happen to have an HTML input somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

[IndexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) will find the first instance of a given character

```
if (theElement.value.indexOf(".") !== -1) {
    // Yes, it has a dot
}
```

Comment: @devnull69: The question is about a `change` handler, so by definition what's being checked is a string. That said, the question is **really** poor and unclear, so they could want to check some variable that isn't the element's value, and which might be a number, in response to a change in the element. Or who knows what.